# How to determine compilation flags at compile time on OS/X?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc

If I compile with -fPIC on x86 Linux with gcc 4.1, then the definition __PIC__ is set to 1 and the preprocessor can act on that at compile time. However, on OS/X under gcc 4.01 that is not the case. Is there some other way to determine the setting of -fPIC at compile time on OS/X?

A general facility for querying compilation flags at the preprocessor level under OS/X would be even more helpful, but I wasn't able to find anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

`-fPIC` is the default on OS X.  gcc 4.0.1 on my crufty old OS X 10.4 machine does define `__PIC__`; or, when it is explicitly turned off with `-fno-PIC`, it does not.

The settings of compilation flags are not in general exported to the preprocessor, except for certain special cases, which may vary across different GCC targets.

But you can see the effects of changing flags on the predefined preprocessor definitions, on any platform, using the `-dM` option to `gcc`, which dumps the preprocessor definitions after preprocessing is complete.

e.g. from a terminal window:

```
$ gcc -xc++ -dM -E /dev/null | sort > /tmp/defaults.txt
$ gcc -fno-PIC -xc++ -dM -E /dev/null | sort > /tmp/nopic.txt
$ diff /tmp/defaults.txt /tmp/nopic.txt
65d64
< #define __PIC__ 1
$
```

(I've specified `-xc++` there because I'm preprocessing `/dev/null` rather than a file with an extension that indicates the language variant.  That could also be `-xc`, `-xobjective-c` or `-xobjective-c++`.)

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful information. I should have mentioned that I was building a .S file, and it turns out that -fPIC is apparently not the default when running gcc as a preprocessor, or when assembling. And to complicate things further I had -fPIC on the command line for the assembler, but not the pre-processor.